# else if loop not working?

Tags: java, android, if-statement

Hey I am making a game loop for android but when I check for collisions it doesn't detect. I am using this if else loop and when I tried debugging I found out that it checks only for the 1st statement and then skips all other. Thanks in advance.

```
    mx = g.ttx;
    my = g.tty;
    int width=g.getrW(); 
    int Height=g.getrH();


    if (mx + (width / 2) - 22 < x + radius && my < y + radius) {
        if (mx +( width / 2) - 70 > x && my + Height > y) {
            gameOver = true;
            m.start();
        }
    } else if (mx + 26 < x + radius && my + 26 < y + radius) {
        if (mx + width - 45 > x && (my + Height - 45) > y) {
            gameOver = true;
            m.start();
        }
    } else if (mx + (width / 2) - 30 < x + radius && my + 10 < y + radius) {
        if (mx + width - 74 > x && my - 20 + Height > y) {
            gameOver = true;
            m.start();
        }
      }
```

Comment: does g.getrW() and g.getrH() return the same value each time it's called? If so, probably best to call them before the if, just for performance sake (you have the potential to make 6 less method calls), might make it bit more readable too.

Comment: You can combine the `else if`s with the nested `if`s they contain, might make things clearer and easier to debug. But without more context, can't say more than that

Comment: Did you intend that if an outer `if` is true, but its inner `if` is false, then the remaining outer `if`s will be skipped?  Because that's what happens here.  If it's not what you want, you should use another `&&` to merge each inner `if` with the outer `if` that encloses it.

Comment: yeah they return same value they are widht and Height

Comment: @DavidWallace But I used {} after every if

Comment: Yes, but the `else`s only apply to the outer `if`s.  So if the first outer `if` is true, and the first inner `if` is false, then the `else if` clauses won't be evaluated.

Comment: @DavidWallace  can you please explain it by an example

Comment: Read Elliott's latest comment under his answer.  I don't know how to make it any clearer than my last two comments plus Elliott's one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question then I believe your math is a bit off and I think you wanted something like,

```
int width = g.getrW();
int height = g.getrH();
int minX = (g.ttx - radius) - (width / 2);
int maxX = (g.ttx + radius) + (width / 2);
int minY = (g.tty - radius) - (height / 2);
int maxY = (g.tty + radius) + (height / 2);
if (x >= minX && x <= maxX && y >= minY && y <= maxY) {
    gameOver = true;
    m.start();
}
```

Comment: may be... but if I do this I didn't get all points  Where I want collision btw thanks bro

Comment: @Anil Edited. I assume that x and y are this.x and this.y?

Comment: no they are position and problem is with else if :)

Comment: @Anil No, nested if(s) work like they always have. if (a) { if (b) {} } else if (c) {} Note that b is only tested if a is true. If a is true then c is not tested. Also, where did all of your magic numbers come from?

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a "bug" in your code... a logic bug. Let's reduce your statement "if/else" statements:

```
if (mx + (width / 2) - 22 < x + radius && my < y + radius) {
    ...
} else if (mx + 26 < x + radius && my + 26 < y + radius) {
    ...
} else if (mx + (width / 2) - 30 < x + radius && my + 10 < y + radius) {
    ...
}
```

Converts to:

```
if        (mx + B - 22 < Rx && my < Ry) {
    ...
} else if (mx + 26 < Rx     && my + 26 < Ry) {
    ...
} else if (mx + B - 30 < Rx && my + 10 < Ry) {
    ...
}
```

So, if "my < Ry" is "FALSE" then the next two statements are also "FALSE".
If "mx + B - 22" is "FALSE" then statement #3 is also "FALSE". And if "(width / 2)" is greater than "48", statement 2 is also always "FALSE" ([mx + 48 - 22] == [mx + 26]).

So, in your first "if" statement, if either part of the logic is false, then statement #3 will never be called and statement #2 is unlikely to be called, depending on "width".

You probably have a problem in that logic, but I can't tell you what you "should" do for collision detection. But I believe this answers your question.